# Ignore on mouse down for certain colliders in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game object click-able to select it, the game object in question is a building in a top down game,

Here is what is looks like:
[image]

Notice how it has a 2d box collider on parent i.e. pfLumberMill and a polygon collider on the child Visual object, The function of the child's collider is for obstacle detection in a grid, here is what I mean :
[image]

Now I have a  OnMouseDown on building.cs which is attached to the parent pfLumberMill, the purpose of the OnMouseDown is to select that building, i.e. :

```
    private void OnMouseDown() {
        // select building
        // only triggered where the outer box collider doesn't intersect with the inner polygon collider :(
    }
```

But what is happening is I can select the building only when I click the outer box collider that doesn't collide with the inner polygon collider, I think what happening is the inner collider hit takes precedence over the outer collider hit,
[image]

Was thinking of finding the world space on map click and figuring out the selectable area like that, but is there a easier way to this?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEiqo.png): https://i.stth ack.imgur.com/pOEwk.png

Comment: Do you need raycasts on the obstacle collider? If not you can just have the child on a Layer which ignores raycasts.

Comment: I put the child layer in the Layer mask ,does'n't seem to solve the issue

Comment: did you try putting it on the Ignore Raycast layer?

Comment: put what on ignore raycast layer the visual game object? It should be obstacle layer for the obstacle detection to work

Comment: You could treat the ignore raycast layer as your obstacle layer, could you not? Aside from that there really isn't much you could do to easily hack in your desired result. `OnMouseDown` is convenient, but you have to pay with a lack of control. You'll probably have to make a raycast yourself, get the component and call the now public function.

Comment: I added a second onmousedown on the child collider calling the same functionality, it works for now, kinda hacky tho

Answer (score -1):

I would **put the collider you cant hit in front of the collider you can hit**. Then I would use a script to see if you clicked the behind one.
To see how to check if they clicked on anything, see [this link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/615771/how-to-check-if-click-mouse-on-object.html)

I would only reccomend doing one thing differently.

- Assign a variable for your camera, then assign it in start. Then use that variable to screenpointtoray.

```
Camera cam;
void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
}
void Update()
{
   ......
    //Don't do this: Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(...
    //Do this: cam.ScreenPointToRay(...
   ......
}
```